# Persisting a OneToMany Entity gives javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.ejb.EJBException

Tags: jpa, persistence, ejb, jpa-2.0, one-to-many

When i try the save method, it gives me an error but when i try inserting the data directly to the database manually, it works fine. Please is there something am not adding or seeing in my managedbean class? Please Help to keep the explanation as simple and straight as possible. Thanks

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "state")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "State.findAll", query = "SELECT s FROM State s"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "State.findByStateId", query = "SELECT s FROM State s WHERE s.stateId = :stateId"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "State.findByStateName", query = "SELECT s FROM State s WHERE s.stateName = :stateName")})
public class State implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "state_id")
    private Integer stateId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "state_name")
    private String stateName;
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_id", referencedColumnName = "country_id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Country countryId;
}
```

This the country Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "country")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Country.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Country c"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Country.findByCountryId", query = "SELECT c FROM Country c WHERE c.countryId = :countryId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Country.findByCountryName", query = "SELECT c FROM Country c WHERE c.countryName = :countryName")})
public class Country implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "country_id")
    private Integer countryId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "country_name")
    private String countryName;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "countryId")
    private List<State> stateList;
}
```

ManagedBean

```
public class stateManagedBean {
    @EJB
    private SessionBean sessionBean;
    @EJB
    private stateSessionBean stateSessionBean;
    private State state = new State();

    public stateManagedBean() {

    }
    public State getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(State state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public void save(){
        stateSessionBean.persist(state);
    }        
}
```

Error Page

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.ejb.EJBException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)



Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Bean Validation constraint(s) violated while executing Automatic Bean Validation on callback event:'prePersist'. Please refer to embedded ConstraintViolations for details.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.listeners.BeanValidationListener.validateOnCallbackEvent(BeanValidationListener.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.listeners.BeanValidationListener.prePersist(BeanValidationListener.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.DescriptorEventManager.notifyListener(DescriptorEventManager.java:698)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the exception log clearly states, you have a `ConstraintViolationException`. In your case, the exception is caused by the `@NotNull` annotation, that is generated by a `PrePersist` method in your `JPA` implementation.

Removing the `@NotNull` annotation of the `stateId` and `stateName` fields will help, but you'll probably get another exception from your database. Just to give you an idea, if the `@NotNull` annotation has been automatically generated by your IDE, this is probably due to the fields definition in the db table. If this is your case, and you are using a MySql db like me, you'll get:

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Duplicate key or integrity constraint violation message from server: "Column 'state_id' cannot be null"
```

In this case, you probably want to give an `stateId` and a `stateName` to your State in your bean (and avoid removing the `@NotNull` annotations):

```
state.setStateId(1);
state.setStateName("MyState");
```

Finally, if you have set also the `country_id` as a not-optional field, like the annotation suggests, you have also to assign a country to your state as well, before persisting it.

Comment: Thanks perissf, i will try your suggestion.